# Armadillo C++ library - C++11 compiler required error

Tags: swift, xcode, c++11, armadillo, bridging-header

I'm using MacOS 10.15.7 with Xcode 12.4, I want to use Armadillo library in my iOS Swift project. So first I installed Armadillo through Homebrew.

Armadillo was installed in path `/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/`

I found header files in path `/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/10.5.1/include` and library files in path `/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/10.5.1/lib`

In Xcode project, **Build settings** I provided the above paths in Header Search path and Library search path.

I'm getting below three errors.

- `/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/10.5.1/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_check.hpp:50:4: error: "*** C++11 compiler required; enable C++11 mode in your compiler, or use an earlier version of Armadillo"`
- `/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/10.5.1/include/armadillo:23:10: error: 'cstdlib' file not found #include <cstdlib>`
- `<unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header`

Not sure how to proceed.. Any suggestions ???

Comment: Have you tried following the advice in the error message and "use an earlier version of Armadillo" ?  Looking through the source of Armadillo 9.900, use of C++11 is optional.  In Armadillo 10.5 (the version you are using), C++11 is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do this easily. Swift does not yet support C++ interop, but this is a long term goal. You can read about in the [C++ Interop Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/CppInteroperabilityManifesto.md) in the Swift git repo. The best you will be able to do right now is write an `extern "C"` wrapper in C++ around any C++ functions you want to call, and then import your wrapper into Swift. Since you're using an Xcode project, I would recommend trying something like [this](https://www.swiftprogrammer.info/swift_call_cpp.html).

Alternatively, depending on what you need Armadillo for, you might be able to by away without it. If you just need to do linear algebra, Apple includes LAPACK (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/solving_systems_of_linear_equations_with_lapack)) and BLAS (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/blas)) inside Accelerate, which is available on all Apple platforms without installing anything. This might even be familiar to you because Armadillo does its matrix decompositions through LAPACK. There's also Quadrature (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/quadrature)) if you are looking for integration. I've had good experiences with each of these.